# Should I publish transforms with future stamps to keep them "valid"?

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When writing a custom transform publisher and messing with the transform timestamps, a common problem I face is that other subsystems that end up using the transform sometimes encounter the extrapolation error

```
Extrapolation Error: Lookup would require extrapolation into the future.
```

One way I brush this problem under the rug is to just publish the transform with a stamp slightly in the future to keep them valid.

This obviously looks hacky.  So what is the correct way of publishing transforms such that other nodes can properly look up transforms without facing the extrapolation error?

An example is `base_local_planner` throwing Extrapolation Error when looking up transform `/map -> /odom`, which is a transform that I'm manually publishing.  I tried publishing at various different frequencies but only changing the stamp to be slightly in the future (e.g. now + ros::Duration(0.5)) fixes the issue.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/341092/should-i-publish-transforms-with-future-stamps-to-keep-them-%22valid%22?/) by [Rufus](https://answers.ros.org/users/34739/rufus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1083 on 2020-01-06

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The correct way to do this is that the TF broadcaster publishes the transform with the correct time stamp (no future-dating), and the client nodes should wait for the transform to become available before looking it up:

http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/tf%20and%20Time%20%28C%2B%2B%29#Wait_for_transforms

For example, in Kinetic, base_local_planner does it like this:

https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/99af6694557fdea046a8bd2b761b484709cd61b8/base_local_planner/src/goal_functions.cpp#L188-L193

In Melodic, base_local_planner has switched to TF2, and in TF2 it's possible to pass the timeout directly to lookupTransform:

https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/0f6b9f152cb9317da526f883fc154810fc4e9af0/base_local_planner/src/goal_functions.cpp#L180-L182

So what both versions do is the same: They wait for up to 0.5 seconds for the TF transform with the proper time stamp and then look up the transform. If you get these errors, maybe you have more than 0.5 seconds latency? Another reason for this kind of error is when the TF broadcaster node runs on a different PC than the TF listener and the two clocks are not synchronized.

And by the way: one of the "default" nodes for publishing the `map -> odom` transform is AMCL, and it does indeed future-stamp the TFs that it broadcasts by `transform_tolerance_` (by default 0.1 seconds):

https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/melodic-devel/amcl/src/amcl_node.cpp#L1440-L1441

The successor to AMCL, robot_localization, also provides this option (but it's off by default):

https://github.com/cra-ros-pkg/robot_localization/blob/6956176041630361364c06f554e319988e251300/src/ros_filter.cpp#L1951

I think the reason for doing this is that the `map->odom` transform usually doesn't change that fast (it's only a correction offset), and future-dating it reduces latency in all the `waitForTransform` calls in the client nodes. But I 100% agree with you, it's a hack and it has always bothered me a little.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2020-01-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3